# Keras mode.fit - Why does every new run produce different results (Accuracy and loss)?

Tags: python, keras

Here is the code:

```
model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(1,9000)),
                     keras.layers.Dense(100, activation=tf.nn.relu),
                     keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.softmax)])


model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
         loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',            
         metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_split=0.20,epochs = 10, shuffle=False, verbose =1)
```

With every new run I get different loss and accuracy values for each epoch. I expect consistent results, how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

With every new model initialization you start with new random weights. In order to get reproducible results in keras read here:

https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development

Comment: Thanks, I tried all of that but I still get different results.